# How to unzip the base64 encoded zip files using java

Tags: java, base64

I having a zip flders as base64encode. I need to unzip the Base64zip files and store it into new folder path.

```
public class UnzipBase64ZipFolder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String base64EncodedZip = "BASE64_ENCODED_STRING_HERE"; // Replace with your actual Base64 encoded string
        String outputDirectory = "output_folder"; // Replace with the desired output directory

        byte[] zipData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedZip);

        File directory = new File(outputDirectory);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }

        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipData))) {
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Processing entry: " + entry.getName());

                String entryPath = outputDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
                File entryFile = new File(entryPath);

                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    entryFile.mkdirs();
                } else {
                    try (BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(entryFile))) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        while ((len = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                    }
                }

                zipInputStream.closeEntry();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Base64 encoded zip folder successfully unzipped.");
    }
}
```

From the above code, I can unzip and store only the empty files (0kb). But I want to unzip and store the files with exact data's.

Can any one help me to solve this task? Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious about where this comes from.  It is unusual to use zip to REDUCE the size of files, and then base64 encode, which makes them GROW by 33%.

Comment: This code would also save non-empty files. Check your zips, they're probably filled with empty files. There are various nits to pick with this code, but 'can only write 0kb files' is not one of them. Voting to close - insufficient detail.

Comment: I have used the same base64 in javascript to download the zip file and it's working. I can view the files with data's @rzwitserloot

Comment: I have a zipped base 64 CSV files which I get from server side as response. Now I want to exact and store the csv files

Comment: @VigneshRamamoorthy You are saying: "The code works fine". A casual glance at the code from g00se and me also tells us: Well, sure, this doesn't have the problem your title mentions. Hence: We do not understand what your question is.